# To use DynamoDB or Redis on our service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I am implementing a new service wherein I am planning to use Redis or DynamoDB but not sure which one to pick.
The working would be something like:

1. Get data from front-end store it in DB.
2. If the front end sends one more request, then forward the data stored in the database and delete it later.
3. Else, if the front end does not send one more request we can delete the data stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Redis or DynamoDB

These 2 are different services - Redis is open-source, in-memory key-value data store for use as a database, cache, message broker, and queue.It is in-memory cache service that can be used to improve the performance of database operations whereas DynamoDB is fully managed NoSQL database service.

All Redis data resides in-memory, in contrast to DynamodDB databases that store data on disk. DynamoDB is a SSD Database comparing to Redis in-memory store, but it is possible to use DAX - DynamoDB accelerator which is in-memory cache read replica for DynamoDB as accelerator on read intensive load

> Get data from front-end store it in DB.

Use DynamoDB if you are fine with No-SQL based database solution. This is recommended database solution for mobile, web, gaming, ad tech, IoT, and other applications that need low-latency data access at any scale

> If the front end sends one more request, then forward the data stored
> in the database and delete it later.

DynamodDB can scale automatically with 2 operation modes 1. Provisioned and 2.On-demand

1. Provisioned - If you choose provisioned mode, you specify the number of reads and writes per second that you require for your application. You can use auto scaling to adjust your table’s provisioned capacity automatically in response to traffic changes
2. On-demand - This is a flexible billing option capable of serving thousands of requests per second without capacity planning.

Either of the above 2 can be used for your mentioned use case.

> if the front end does not send one more request we can delete the data
> stored.

There is a TTL (Time to live) property - which allows you to define a per-item timestamp to determine when an item is no longer needed. Shortly after the date and time of the specified timestamp, DynamoDB deletes the item from your table without consuming any write throughput- associated with Items in the DynamoDB table

You can make use of it to purge/delete the data stored after certain duration